Using FluentAssertions .Should().NotBeNull() instead of Assert.NotNull(record.Message) give a Possible NullReference smell
I have a little question about FluentAssertions and record.Should().NotBeNull();
Here i use XUnit for unit testing and his Record class.
Take this code with Record:
    // i expect this code will explode and the record will be not null
    var record = await Record.ExceptionAsync(() =>
        sut.SomeActionThatExplode(new SomeDto())
    );        

So, here i use XUnit.Assert methods:
    Assert.IsType<InvalidDataException>(record);
    Assert.NotNull(record.Message);
    Assert.Equal("abcs",record.Message); // here all is ok! and i have no smells

I have no smells using this method and everything is fine as i expected.
In the following example i do the same assertion, but using FluentAssertions instead:
    record.Should().BeOfType<InvalidDataException>();
    record.Should().NotBeNull();
    record.Message.Should().NotBeNull(); // here i have a smell issue
    record.Message.Should().Be("abcs");

When i use FluentAssertions i got a Possible 'System.NullReferenceException' smell on the record.Message.Should().NotBeNull() line for the record.
Here a snapshot:

Is there something i do wrong? how can i avoid smell using only FluentAssertion methods?
Maybe i should use a mix of both like this:
    Assert.IsType<InvalidDataException>(record);
    Assert.NotNull(record.Message);
    record.Message.Should().NotBeNull();
    record.Message.Should().Be("abcs"); // that's fine an i got no smells.

However i wish use only FluentAssertions to achieve no smells on my code.
Thanks in advance.
Cose belle!

var message = Assert.NotNull(record.Message); message.Should...

Alternative to the answer below, you could factor out the first two into a private method that takes the record as argument. Then you can annotate the argument with [NotNull] which tells the static analysis that if the method returns, the argument has not been null. That should make the warning go away.

@RubenBartelink i already wrote this solution in my question. i'm just looking for an alternative that use only FluentAssertion.

@Fildor thank you. it could be an alternative. But, i'm just looking for a solution that use FluentAssertions only.

i found opened issues related to the question:
https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/452
https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/1074
As pointed out from the accepted answer user, it's a well known bug of FluentAssertions classes

Faie enough; I have less desire to Fluent all the things - my aim was to lean on the NotNull and the fact that it guarantees its return if it doesnt throw in order to then let normal no-forced evaluation to just work...

The issue you're encountering is a known behavior with FluentAssertions.
Currently the vs static code analyzer doesn't recognize that Should().NotBeNull() guarantees that the object isn't null.
Some Devs are using the null-forgiving operator! in their unit tests to tell the compiler that you're sure the object isn't null.
E.G.:
record.Should().BeOfType<InvalidDataException>();
record.Should().NotBeNull();
record!.Message.Should().NotBeNull();
record!.Message.Should().Be("abcs");

This should resolve the null reference warning while allowing you to continue using FluentAssertions.
However, please note that using ! should be done with caution and im my opinion only in tests.
as it turns off null checking for that reference, which could lead to runtime errors if used in production code.

Ok,this seems to be the only solution, even i dont' like, as you don't, use null checking for free.

This is not a clear solution, but rather a bit of a hack. You can implement a helper tool like this:
public static class FluentAssertionsCompilerCheckExtensions
{
    public static AndConstraint<TAssertions> NotBeNull<TSubject, TAssertions>(
        this ReferenceTypeAssertions<TSubject, TAssertions> assertions,
        out TSubject subject)
        where TAssertions : ReferenceTypeAssertions<TSubject, TAssertions>
    {
        subject = assertions.Subject;
        return assertions.NotBeNull();
    }
}

which will allow you to use it like this:
record.Message.Should().NotBeNull(out var message);
message.Should().Be("abcs"); // no compiler warnings

